# .NET MVC Partial Return jQuery Ajax Inputs dont reset after form submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm confused to why this is not working. I have a form that I need to submit via jquery ajax and get the results back in place. But the input fields are not being reset after a successful submit.

```
@model VendorCreateViewModel

<div id="ajaxVendorContainer">
    <div class="contentareabody">
        <div id="vendorIndexResult">
         @Html.Partial("Vendor/_VendorIndexPartial", Model.PersistedVendors)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table style="width: 100%; border: 0;">
        <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
            <td>
                <div class="contentareabody">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Vendor", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createVendorForm" }))
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.VendorRequestId)
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rowheader">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendorName)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VendorName)
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VendorName)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rowheader">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendorNumber)</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VendorNumber)
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VendorNumber)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rowheader">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendorAddressOrDescription)</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VendorAddressOrDescription)
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VendorAddressOrDescription)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rowheader">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendorAmount)</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on">$</span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VendorAmount)
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VendorAmount)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rowheader">Account Number Helper</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-up"></i></span>
                                        <select id="AccountDropDown" style="width: 315px;">
                                            <option value="0"></option>
                                            <option value="1">My Department - Travel and Meetings - 18</option>
                                            <option value="2">My Department - Training Expense - 20</option>
                                            <option value="3">Different Department - Manual Entry</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <img id="vendor-ajax-loader-account" src="/Content/Images/ajax.gif" style="display: none;" alt="ajax loader" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rowheader">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendorAccountNumber)

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VendorAccountNumber)
                                    </div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VendorAccountNumber)

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="rightoptions">
                    @Html.Partial("EstimatedExpenses/Summary", Model.VendorEstimatedExepensesViewModel)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" onclick="submitForm()" value="Add Vendor" />
    &nbsp;
    <img id="vendor-ajax-loader-add" src="/Content/Images/ajax.gif" style="display: none;" alt="ajax loader" />
    <span id="vendor-working-add" style="display: none;">Adding Vendor...</span>

    <script>

        function submitForm() {
            $('form#createVendorForm').submit();
        }

        $('form#createVendorForm').submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#vendor-ajax-loader-add').show();
                        $('#vendor-working-add').show();
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#ajaxVendorContainer').html(result);
                        $('#vendor-ajax-loader-add').hide();
                        $('#vendor-working-add').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });


        $(function () {
            $('#AccountDropDown').change(function () {
                var rId = '@(Model.VendorRequestId)';
            var aId = $('#AccountDropDown').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Account/GetAccountNumber',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: rId, accountId: aId },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#vendor-ajax-loader-account').show();
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#VendorAccountNumber').val(result);
                    $('#vendor-ajax-loader-account').hide();
                }
            });
        });


    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Any idea whats going on here? You can see the action method is returning empty values for the input fields yet the browser still shows the old pre-form-submitted values

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're handling the submit on you javascript code. You should also take care of the form state, such as resetting it.

Comment: Cant figure out how to do that while still keeping validation working. I don't want to reset the form values if server side validation triggers

Comment: Within the `success` callback.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways reset it. You can reset all the fields by manually clearing them in the success function that is called after your submit. The other way to do it is to return an empty view model in your action result if you database insert succeeds. For example:

```
public actionresult Create(VendorCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return PartialView(viewModel);

    // Converts your view model to your domain model
    VendorModel domainModel = new VendorModel(viewModel);

    // Service call to create your vendor in the database
    vendorService.CreateVendor(domainModel);

    // This will reset your fields to empty
    return PartialView(new VendorCreateViewModel());
}
```

I forgot to add in the second example only works if you are using the built-in ASP.NET MVC-Ajax (i.e. Ajax.BeginForm()).